# Under *nix, how can I find a string within a file within a directory?

Tags: linux, grep

I'm using ubuntu linux, and I use bash from with a terminal emulator every day for many tasks.

I would like to know how to find a string or a substring within a file that is within a particular directory.

If I was knew the file which contained my target substring, I would just cat the file and pipe it through grep, thus:

```
cat file | grep mysubstring
```

But in this case, the pesky substring could be anywhere within a known directory.

How do I hunt down my substring ?

Comment: just as a note... you don't have to pipe cat to grep. grep can read files just fine.

Answer (score 11):

Use a shell wildcard:

```
grep mysubstring *
```

If you want to search subdirectories, use the `-r` option to recurse into them:

```
grep -r myssubstring .
```

Comment: or grep -r mysubstring directory

Answer (score 4):

```
find -type f | xargs grep mysubstring
```

These commands (`find`, `xargs` and `grep`) have lots of options, so you can tune this operation substantially.

Comment: add `-print0` to find and `-0` to xargs if your files/directories may have spaces in their names: `find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep mysubstring`

Answer (score 4):

say I want to find all the python code files that contain the text "wiki" under the directory "~/projects", here is the script:

```
grep -lir "wiki" ~/projects/**/*.py
```

adjust the script to your specific requirements.

Answer (score 2):

No matter how you do it, don't cat files into grep.  Your original version of

```
cat file | grep mysubstring
```

is more correctly done as

```
grep mysubstring file
```

Comment: although you're right this isn't an actual answer to the question.

Comment: Why are you telling me this?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to do it in batch mode, you could install midnight commander (mc), it can search for strings in files.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find all files with a certain String recursive from "current" dir, use:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l mysubstring {} \;
```

(should work on most *nix')